# Using Selenium to authenticate SAML through redirects

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, jsp, saml

I am working on Selenium testing for a project that is accessed via JSP which uses SAML to authenticate the user. I cannot find a way to provide credentials through to the SAML page, which is accessed through a 302 redirect.

I want to log in to `home.domain.com/run.jsp`. When I visit the page, I get a 302 redirect to `auth.domain.com/adfs/ls/wia?SAMLRequest=<long_token>`, where I fill in the browser's dialog window with my credentials. After submitting them, I am redirected back to `home.domain.com/run.jsp`, but with access this time.

The common Selenium auth answer seems to be adding the credentials to the url (`admin:passw0rd@home.domain.com/run.jsp`), but that doesn't pass the credentials through the redirect, and I even get a warning: *You are about to log in to the site "home.domain.com" with the username "admin", but the website dos not require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you.*

Comment: Why not send keys to provide your username/password when prompted?  Depending on the implementation you may be providing that to the authentication server directly.

Comment: @pcalkins As far as I've been able to tell, Selenium can't touch with those fields since it's something that the browser handles, as opposed to something like an Alert window which is controlled through the web page. I set up the Actions object to try to do that, but no luck -- it can SendKeys to html elements, but that popup is not html. If you found an example of that though, that would totally be a solution.

Comment: if this is domain-based login just login manually and use that profile when you initialize the driver.

Comment: ...so at that point the browser is using a key in your machine's key store to verify a user on the domain.

Comment: That worked locally, but not on our deployment server. I wouldn't be surprised if Chrome wasn't even installed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for this ended up waiting for the redirect, then add the credentials to the current url and re-load the authentication page. If somebody has a better answer, I'd accept it because this is definitely hacky.

```cs
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("home.domain.com/run.jsp");
Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait for redirects

// if the SAML didn't automatically authenticate and return us to the homepage
if (driver.Url.Contains("SAMLRequest")
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(driver.Url.Replace("://", "://admin:passw0rd@"));
}
```